# Minimizing a very noisy 6-parameters function with simplex and a genetic algorithm - ¨Python language

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, minimization, simplex

I'm trying to minimize a loss function between empirical human data and simulated data from a 6-parameters cognitive model. The model is very noisy. Note that the model is programmed in PYTHON.

The standard method is to use a Simplex search. However, Simplex is very dependent on the initial guess, and the risk to capture a local minimum is high. So I have two questions:

1) I'm wondering if a genetic algorithm could not be used to first search for an approximate position of the global minimum first, and use the result as a starting point for the simplex search. If it is a good idea, does someone know a good implementation of an appropriate genetic algorithm in python?

2) Which reflection, expansion, and contraction constant should I use for the Simplex search?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Mat

Answer (score 4):

Since your function is very noisy, have few dimensions and you are open to try evolutionary algorithm, I would recommend you to actually replace your Simplex optimization process by the Covariance Matrix Adaptation Evolution Strategy.

The algorithm is recognized by the black-box optimization community to be one of the most efficient for complex problem under 50 dimensions. It is described in details by its author  : [here](http://www.lri.fr/~hansen/cmaesintro.html).

The author provides implementation of its algorithm in Python [here](http://www.lri.fr/~hansen/cmaes_inmatlab.html#python%20%22Python%20implementation%22.). The evolutionary algorithms framework [DEAP](http://deap.googlecode.com/) also provides a Python implementation of CMA-ES and different examples of application, which I find easier to use (disclaimer, I am one of the main developers of DEAP).